# Why am I getting an error saying that my function type is conflicting? (edited)

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a code in `C` about a type of encryption.

*My code:*

```
#include<stdio.h>


int* number_split(int x)
{
    int arr[5],i=0,j=0;
    static int ar1[5];
    while(x!=0)
    {
        x=x%10;
        arr[i]=x;
        ++i;
    }
     for(i=4;i<=0;i--)
    {
        ar1[j]=arr[i];
        ++j;
    }
    return ar1;
}


int main()
{
    int n,k,*arr,i=0,l;
    printf("Please enter any number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Please enter a key:");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    arr=number_split(n);
    l=k%5;
    for(i=l;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I had looked up into the internet and found that static or globally declared arrays can be returned to other functions. So, I decided to modify my code, but now the problem is that I am getting `Segmentation fault(core dumped)` and I don't know why. Can someone please help me?

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` is the size of a pointer? Let me think. Maybe not what you required

Comment: Please provide the complete error message. Where do you use dynamic memory allocation? How do you allocate without using any of malloc and friends?

Comment: Well, I had checked it from this site https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/return-local-array-c-function/, and I used the code here.

Comment: Please don't invent the abbreviation "DMA" because it's already taken and means Direct Memory Access.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your method before using it, like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int* reverse(int* ar);
void number_split(int x)
{
  ...
```

or, of course, you could simply move the definition of your reverse method before using it, i.e. before defining the number split method.

---

> So I tried using dynamic memory allocation

Nope, I mean not as far as I can tell, there is no dynamic memory allocation anywhere happening in your code.

You are using a locally defined array instead, and that's why you get this warning (by enabling warnings in your compiler, e.g. Wall, Wextra flags in GCC):

```
main.c:24:12: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
   24 |     return ar1;
      |            ^~~
```

So the issue that here:

```
  int* reverse(int* ar)
  {
    int ar1[5],i=0,j=0;
    // your logic
    return ar1;
  }
```

by the time you return the array, the method will have terminated, and since that array was a local variable to that method, it will go out of scope, its lifetime will end (and will be destroyed).

That means, that when the caller would like to use that array, there is no array left in memory to be used, so the caller will just use some memory filled with garbage.

Here, you *could* [dynamically allocate the array](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/dynamic-array-in-c/), which typically, in a correct program, will stay on memory until you, explicitly, ask for its de-allocation.

---

> error saying that my function type is conflicting?

Because the prototype of the method is:

```
void number_split(int x);
```

but you are calling it like this:

```
arr = number_split(n);
```

even though its return type is void. Thus the warning:

```
main.c:34:8: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
   34 |     arr=number_split(n);
      |        ^
```

Comment: But the thing is, the void method `number_split` calls another non-void method `reverse` which returns an array, and I am trying to fetch that array. Hence `arr = number_split(n);`.

Comment: So what @FMA? `number_split()`'s prototype returns void. If you want to return something from that method too, then you need to change the return type too.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the program does not make sense and if it will even compile has undefined behavior.

For example in this for loop

```
for(i=sizeof(ar);i<=0;i--)
```

there is used `sizeof( int * )`. It seems you mean

```
for(i=sizeof(ar1);i<=0;i--)
```

And the function returns a pointer to a local array that will not be alive after exiting the function.

```
int ar1[5],i=0,j=0;
//...
return ar1;
```

Or this loop

```
while(x!=0)
{
    x=x%10;
    arr[i]=x;
    ++i;
}
```

has at most two iterations due to this statement

```
    x=x%10;
```

It seems you mean

```
do
{
    arr[i] = x % 10;
    ++i;
} while ( x /= 10 );
```

The function `number_split` declared like

```
void number_split(int x)
```

has the return type void. But you are using the return type to assign it to a pointer

```
int n,k,*arr,i=0,l;
// ...
arr=number_split(n);
```

And the function `reverse` shall be declared before the function `number_split`.

Answer (score 0):

`number_split` is defined as to not return anything:

```
void number_split(int x)
```

yet you expect it to return something:

```
arr=number_split(n);
```

Even if you define it to return the correct type, which would be

```
int *number_split(int x)
```

you let it return a *local* variable `arr`. But that variable won't exist after the function returns. So you either need to pass it the array in which to return the result, or let it allocate memory using `malloc`. I leave that as an excercise for you.